# VSS event log error every three hours (System.Writer Access denied)

Tags: windows-server-2012, service, vss

In my event log (Windows Server 2012) I see this error every three hours, going back a very long time:

> Volume Shadow Copy Service error: Unexpected error querying for the
>   IVssWriterCallback interface.  hr = 0x80070005, Access is denied. .
>   This is often caused by incorrect security settings in either the
>   writer or requestor process.
>
> Operation:    Gathering Writer Data
>
> Context:    Writer Class Id: {e8132975-6f93-4464-a53e-1050253ae220}
>   Writer Name: System Writer
>   Writer Instance ID:
>   {7d2e834e-3414-492a-9009-514581a351ee}

A search showed other people having trouble with their third-party backup software that uses VSS, but the suggestions haven't worked for me.

Here is what I've tried.

1. Used `vssadmin list writers` in a DOS window to show the VSS service statuses.  This showed three services awaiting completion.  I then re-started them manually and ran the third-party backup software manually.  The services showed *"stable - no error"* on completion, but on the three hour mark the errors returned and the status switched back to "awaiting completion".  This makes me think the problem lies outside the backup software.
2. Re-registered SqlVDI as per [this answer](http://www.aomeitech.com/forum/discussion/2957/vss-witer-errors-with-ab-tech-3-5-on-sbs-2011#Item_8), but no luck.

Can anyone cast any light on what might cause this, and how to prevent it?  Perhaps there's a way to view what is triggering a scheduled event every three hours?